# VBA joining strings n times

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to join strings n number of times, I need to first extract the text between "(" and ")", and then join them, the strings typically looks like this

`Black Iron Oxide (CI 77499)/ Red Iron Oxide (CI 77491)/ Yellow Iron Oxide (CI 77492)`

This would be the soulution I'm looking for

[image: solution]

Here is what I've tried, this works but it only replaces the content in the cell `i, lastcol + 1` "newcount" number of times, I know I need to use something like

`Oldvalue & " / " & Newvalue`

But i don't know how to fit this in here

```
Dim StartPos, EndPos, newcount, i, a As Integer
Dim StrEx, Oldvalue, Newvalue As String

For i = rcount - Count To 4 Step -1
    StrEx = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value
    newcount = Len(StrEx) - Len(Replace(StrEx, "(", ""))
        If Len(StrEx) - Len(Replace(StrEx, "(", "")) = 0 Then
        Else
            For a = 1 To newcount Step 1
                StrEx = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value
                StartPos = InStr(StrEx, "(")
                EndPos = InStr(StrEx, ")")
                Oldvalue = Mid(StrEx, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StrEx, Oldvalue, "", 1)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, lastcol0 + 1).Value = Oldvalue
            Next a
        End If
Next i
```

```
rcount = number of the last row 
Count = could be set to 0 in this example
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Regular Expression

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar
    Dim regex As Object, m As Object, s As String
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long

    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\(CI \d\d\d\d\d\))" ' pattern
    End With

    Set ws = Sheets(1)
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 4 To lastrow
            s = .Cells(r, "G")
            If regex.test(s) Then
               Set m = regex.Execute(s)
               ReDim ar(1 To m.Count)
               For i = 1 To m.Count
                  ar(i) = m(i - 1)
               Next
            
               ' text
               .Cells(r, "H") = regex.Replace(s, "")
               
                ' CI ref
               .Cells(r, "I") = Join(ar, "/")
            End If
        Next
    End With
   
    MsgBox lastrow - 3 & " rows processed", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way since you tagged Excel-Formula too:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A3,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,LET(z,TEXTSPLIT(y,"/ "),HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" / ",,LEFT(z,LEN(z)-11)),TEXTJOIN(" / ",,MID(z,LEN(z)-9,10))))))),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the raw data is contained in column A. The results after processing will be written out to columns C and D.

```vb
Option Base 1
Sub demo()
    Dim lstRow, res()
    Dim aSplit, bSplit, b, i
    Dim sDeli As String
    Dim sTxt As String, sNum As String
    lstRow = [a1].End(xlDown).Row
    ReDim res(lstRow, 2)
    sDeli = " / "
    arr = [a1].Resize(lstRow, 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        sTxt = ""
        sNum = ""
        aSplit = Split(Trim(arr(i, 1)), "/")
        For Each b In aSplit
            bSplit = Split(b, " (")
            sTxt = sTxt & sDeli & Trim(bSplit(0))
            sNum = sNum & sDeli & "(" & bSplit(1)
        Next
        res(i, 1) = Mid(sTxt, 3)
        res(i, 2) = Mid(sNum, 3)
    Next
    Range("C:D").Clear
    [c1].Resize(lstRow, 2).Value = res()
End Sub
```

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Black Iron Oxide (CI 77499)/ Red Iron Oxide (CI 77491)/ Yellow Iron Oxide (CI 77492) |  | Black Iron Oxide / Red Iron Oxide / Yellow Iron Oxide | (CI 77499) / (CI 77491) / (CI 77492) |
| Black Iron Oxide (CI 77499)/ Red Iron Oxide (CI 77491) |  | Black Iron Oxide / Red Iron Oxide | (CI 77499) / (CI 77491) |
| Red Iron Oxide (CI 77491) |  | Red Iron Oxide | (CI 77491) |

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the following routine. It handles one cell (that means you will have to call it from the loop over your data) and writes the result into the two cells next to the cell.

Basically, the routine uses the VBA function `Split` to get a list of elements and then loop over those elements to separate the name from the CI number. Both pieces are collected in arrays. After the loop finished, the two result arrays are written into the cells using `Join`.

```
Sub SplitMyString(cell As Range)
    Dim elements() As String, i As Long
    elements = Split(cell.Value, "/")
    ReDim elementNames(0 To UBound(elements))
    ReDim elementCI(0 To UBound(elements))
    
    For i = LBound(elements) To UBound(elements)
        Dim p As Long
        p = InStr(elements(i), "(")
        If p > 0 Then
            elementNames(i) = Trim(Left(elements(i), p - 1))
            elementCI(i) = Trim(Mid(elements(i), p))
        Else
            elementNames(i) = elements(i)
        End If
    Next i
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = Join(elementNames, " / ")
    cell.Offset(0, 2) = Join(elementCI, " / ")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little restructuring, you can `Split` the string and then extract the old and the new:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim rcount As Long
    Dim lastcol0 As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        rcount = .Cells(.Rows.count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol0 = 8 ' ???
    
        Dim count As Long
        count = 0
    
        Dim i As Long
        For i = rcount - count To 4 Step -1
        
            Dim originalText As String
            originalText = .Cells(i, "G").Value
            
            Dim elements() As String
            elements = Split(originalText, "/")
            
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(elements) To UBound(elements)
                Dim element As String
                element = elements(j)
                
                Dim oldValue As String
                Dim newValue As String
                oldValue = Trim$(Left$(element, InStr(1, element, "(") - 1))
                newValue = Trim$(Right$(element, _
                                 Len(element) - InStr(1, element, "(") + 1))
                .Cells(i + j, "G").Value = oldValue
                .Cells(i + j, "H").Value = newValue
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```